# Option menu not visible in CameraPreview demo

Tags: java, android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I'm trying out the [CameraPreview sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.html) code from google on an Android 3.1 device.

I created a new android project and added the CameraPreview.java, the res/menu/camera_menu.xml and strings.xml files and edited the AndroidManifest.xml so it can use the camera.

But the option menu does not show up. It doesn't even call the onCreateOptionsMenu() altogether.

Why doesn't Android call the onCreateOptionsMenu() ? Did I miss something?

Comment: You have pressed the 'menu' button on the device haven't you?

Comment: @NickT : The honeycomb (3.1) device (Samsung galaxy tab) only has virtual buttons, but the menu button does not appear.